# Kartik Editable in Kartik DetailView failed update data

Tags: json, yii2, kartik-v

I'm trying to update data in Kartik-DetailView using Kartik-Editable in my Yii2 project.

Here is my code in

*view.php*:

```
<?php
echo DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'mode' => DetailView::MODE_VIEW,
    'attributes' => [
     [
            'class' => kartik\grid\EditableColumn::class,
            'attribute' => 'busFleetStatus',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => Editable::widget([
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'busFleetStatus',
                'asPopover' => true,
                'beforeInput' => function($form, $widget) {
                    echo $form->field($widget->model, 'busFleetStatus')->widget(\kartik\select2\Select2::classname(), [
                        'data' => ArrayHelper::map(SystemStatus::find()->where(['statusCode' => 'busFleetStatus'])->all(), 'systemStatusId', 'statusDetail'),
                    ])->label(false);
                },
                'displayValueConfig' => [
                    1 => 'Available',
                    2 => 'Maintenance',
                ],
                'format' => Editable::FORMAT_LINK,
                'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_SELECT2,
            ]),
        ],
        .... //another code
   ],
])
?>
```

and set the action in controller like this

*BusFleetController.php*:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    if (Yii::$app->request->post('hasEditable')) {
        $_id = Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
        $model = BusFleet::findOne($_id);

        $out = Json::encode(['output'=>'', 'message'=>'']);

        $post = [];
        $posted = current($_POST['BusFleet']);
        $post['BusFleet'] = $posted;

        if ($model->load($post)) {
            if ($model->save()) {
                if (isset($posted['busFleetStatus'])) {
                    $output = $model->busFleetStatus;
                }
                $out = \yii\helpers\Json::encode(['output' => $output, 'message' => '']);
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

But I got a **json** error, I've check through debugger in mozilla browser, and in the *Params* tab I got nothing, I didn't get the **JSON** data like `hasEditable` `editableIndex`, etc.

I've done several test from another issue or tutorial, but I got this same issue. I just following the way another body do.

The error  image

[image]

### Update

My view use GET as request method.

Comment: when do you get this error when you open editable popup or change the select option?

Comment: I got the error when click save/submit